# Regular expression to distinguish between single and multiple digit numbers

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a regular expression for capturing repeating numerical patterns in a string of number. However, it is not able to distinguish between single and multiple digits within a number.

Given a string:

> 0 5 0 0 0 16 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 11 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 11 1 4 4 4 16

and regular expression

```
(\d+)( \1)+
```

the match result is

> 0 5 ***0 0 0*** 16 ***1 1 1 1*** 3 ***1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 11 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1*** 2 1 ***1 1*** ***4 4 4*** 16

The regex is not able to distinguish between 1 and 11.

(Note: 11 could also be a repeating number and maximum 3 digits are possible in a number)

Comment: "match result"? Match doesn't match the "0 5" at the start of the string. Can you post a running example so we can see what regex calls you use. Also, what do you want to happen? Can you include an expected result?

Comment: `(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})([ ]\1)+(?!\d)`or `(?<!\S)(\d{1,3})([ ]\1)+(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a word boundary to regex. For example:

```
(\b\d+)( \1\b)+
```

See https://regex101.com/r/ZSCMjF/1